# Rewrite Model in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I want to rewrite the Magento 1 model `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector`

```
protected function _initRetrievers()
```

How can rewrite this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a few files for this:

- `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml`
- `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`
- `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Collector.php`

Let's first declare your module
 `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_Module>
      </modules>
    </config>
```

Then let's create the module configuration file `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
      </modules>

      <global>
        <models>
          <sales>
            <rewrite>
              <quote_address_total_collector>Namespace_Module_Model_Collector</quote_address_total_collector>
            </rewrite>
          </sales>
        </models>
      </global>
    </config>
```

Finally, let's create your model `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Collector.php`

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Address Total Collector model
     *
     * @category   Namespace
     * @package    Namespace_Module
     */
    class Namespace_Module_Model_Collector extends Mage_Sales_Model_Config_Ordered
    {
        /**
         * Initialize retrievers array
         *
         * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector
         */
        protected function _initRetrievers()
        {
            //add your custom code here
            //remove whatever you don't need or want to modify below

            $sorts = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SALES_TOTALS_SORT, $this->_store);
            foreach ($sorts as $code => $sortOrder) {
                if (isset($this->_models[$code])) {
                    // Reserve enough space for collisions
                    $retrieverId = 100 * (int) $sortOrder;
                    // Check if there is a retriever with such id and find next available position if needed
                    while (isset($this->_retrievers[$retrieverId])) {
                        $retrieverId++;
                    }
                    $this->_retrievers[$retrieverId] = $this->_models[$code];
                }
            }
            ksort($this->_retrievers);
            $notSorted = array_diff(array_keys($this->_models), array_keys($sorts));
            foreach ($notSorted as $code) {
                $this->_retrievers[] = $this->_models[$code];
            }
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <quote_address_total_collector>Namespace_Module_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector</quote_address_total_collector>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
```

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Collector.php

```
<?php 

class Namespace_Module_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: caught Error: Call to a member function getCollectors() this error shown